# How to compute k'th tensor power of matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

Is there a 1-liner to compute $M^{\otimes k}$ where $M$ is some matrix and $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html)? The documentation says I can write

```
Z = {{1,0},{0,-1}};
KroneckerProduct[Z,Z]
```

What I'd like is some way (eg a function KroneckerPower[M_,k_]) that does this for $k$ copies of $M$.

Comment: `KroneckerPower[m_, k_] := KroneckerProduct @@ Table[m, k]`

Comment: @Natas that does what I asked for. An additional annoying feature that I hadn't anticipated when I asked is that this gives an error if you call ```KroneckerPower[M,1]''' whereas I'd like it to return M. I guess I can just explicitly define the k=1 behaviour though?

Comment: Sure, just define the special cases separately. The Mathematica pattern matcher will (usually) figure out which patterns are more specific. In this case defining `KroneckerPower[m_, 1] := m` should do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Natas' answer, you could also try:

```
kp[m_, k_] := Nest[KroneckerProduct[#, m] &, m, k - 1]
```

or

```
kp[m_List, k_Integer?Positive] := Nest[KroneckerProduct[#, m] &, m, k - 1]
```

These should give you the exact same answer. Using `Nest` doesn't really save you any characters over `Table`, but it is a useful function so I thought I'd use it here. `Nest` applies the function (`KroneckerProduct` here) repeatedly to the previous output of `Nest`. I also use `k - 1` so that when you enter 1 for `k`, you just get back `m`.

In the second one I'm just showing how you can add checks to the function so that it only runs if `m` is a `List` and `k` is an `Integer` greater than 0. It might not matter here, but I often end up running code where I accidentally feed a function the wrong kind of data and then Mathematica sits there printing errors until I abort.